# Spring Kafka Non-Blocking retries

Tags: spring-kafka

I have batch @KafkaListener as follows:

```
    @KafkaListener(
            topicPattern = "ProductTopic", 
            containerFactory = "kafkaBatchListenerFactory")
    public void onBatch(List<Message<String>> messages, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
         consume(messages); // goes to DB
         acknowledgment.acknowledge();
    }
```

I also have 3 more topics created: `ProductTopic.Retry-1`, `ProductTopic.Retry-2` and `ProductTopic.Retry-DLT`. Idea is to consume batch of messages from `ProductTopic`, and to do non-blocking exponential retries if DB bulk insert fails. I would like to publish message to `ProductTopic.Retry-#` each time the retry fails, and finally send it to `ProductTopic.Retry-DLT`. Also lets assume that because of some other limitations, I cannot let the framework create retry and dlt topics for me.

What's the best approach for such situation? Should I use `RetryTopicConfigurer` to configure such logic? How can I manually define names of my retry and dead lettered topics? Should I create @KafkaListener for each of the retry and dl topics?

Or is the best approach to use `RecoveringBatchErrorHandler`?

Please share any examples and good practices on this. I came across lots of comments and support on such topics, but some of the comments are old now and as such related to the older versions of spring-kafka. I can see there are few of the modern approaches to work with batch listeners, but I would also like to ask @Garry Russell and the team to point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The framework non-blocking retry mechanism does not support batch listeners.

**EDIT**

The built-in infrastructure is strongly tied to the `KafkaBackoffAwareMessageListenerAdapter`; you would need to create a version of that implements `BatchAcknowledgingConsumerAwareMessageListener`.

It should then be possible to wrap your existing listener with that but you would also need a custom error handler to send the whole batch to the next retry topic.

It would not be trivial.

Comment: Thanks for reply Gary. Any suggestions how to implement this another way?

Comment: It would not be trivial, but I added some comments.